# HomeKit – Record Stream Video from camera to iPad

Tags: swift, video, ios12, homekit

At the moment HomeKit framework supports three video cameras:

- Logitech Circle 2
- D-Link Omna 180 Cam
- NETGEAR Arlo Baby HD

I'd like to have a possibility to record a video programmatically using Swift.

**Is it possible to record a video from any camera directly to iPad 2017**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment there is no evidence that I can record a stream video from HomeKit cameras to iPad.